# Move a property from one object to another in Javascript

Tags: javascript, graphql

The root of my problem is GraphQL does not allow fields that are not defined by my input type but the data object comes from a single form.

I would love for GraphQL to just ignore the extra field but from what I gathered, that the validation error is built by design.

So now, I need to move the property that GraphQL doesn't know and store it in another variable so I can use it in another mutation.

What I am doing:

```
const items = formData.items

delete formData.items
```

I am just wondering if there is any new/better syntax or technique for doing the same thing.

Comment: Your syntax looks good to me and I don’t know of new/better. But it would apply to any JS object and is not specific to GraphQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) from the original object and use [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to get two new variables, `items` and `newFormData` from your original `formData`:

```js
const { items, ...newFormData } = formData
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing a delete is a code smell. It is better if you do:

```js
const formData = {myProp:8, items:[1,2,3], anotherProp:12}
const {items:items, ...newFormData} = formData

console.log(items)
console.log(newFormData)
```

Comment: Why delete is a code smell?

Comment: Using delete to remove properties in JavaScript can be considered a code smell or bad practice. It can lead to data inconsistencies, impact performance, and make code harder to maintain. It's important to consider alternatives and evaluate the design, performance, memory management, and maintainability implications before using delete.